# Convert Streamlit Image To Numpy Array

Tags: python, image, numpy, streamlit

I was working with streamlit an taking an image(specifically an image of a graph) which was submitted by a user and converting that into a list of points at specific intervals. Is there any way to do this without the use of AI? If I have to use AI, what would be the easiest and most efficient method to go about this?

Here is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
st.title("Object Classification System")
img = st.file_uploader("Upload your image here...", type=['png', 'jpeg'])
if img is not None:
    image = st.image(img, caption='Graph')
    data = np.array(image)
```

However, `data=np.array(image)` is not working properly since the image is not in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open it first as a `PIL Image`, then you can convert it as `numpy array`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image

st.title("Object Classification System")
img = st.file_uploader("Upload your image here...", type=["png", "jpeg"])
if img is not None:
    image = st.image(img, caption="Graph")
    pilimage = Image.open(img).convert("RGB")
    data = np.asarray(pilimage)
    print(data, data.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [np.asarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) nested with [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) to get image byte data in numpy array

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload your image here...", type=['png', 'jpeg'])
if uploaded_file is not None:
    st.image(uploaded_file)
    bytes_data = bytearray(uploaded_file.read())
    file_bytes = np.asarray(bytes_data, dtype=np.uint8)
```